# jQuery chain live handlers?

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I have saved a few divs in variables. I want to bind the same live handler to a bunch of the divs. How do I do it?

```
var div1 = $('#selecto');
var div2 = $('#matic');
var div3 = $('#hello');
$(???).live('click', function() {
   console.log('one of those divs was clicked');
});
// I tried (unsuccessfully) replacing ??? with [div1, div2, div3]
```

Comment: Any reason why you want to use `live` on *existing* elements?

Comment: Ah, I realize now my question makes little sense. Is there any way to get the selector strings from a jQuery $() object?

Comment: You can get it with the `.selector` property. But if you only want to combine those elements, you can use `.add()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
$('#selecto, #matic, #hello').live('click', function() {
   console.log('one of those divs was clicked');
});
```

Comment: Funny, I posted the comment before Felix Kling.  Sorry bud, but this is the way to go.  I'm fuzzy on your logic...

Answer (score 2):

Due to how [**`.live()`**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) works, you cannot combine several jQuery objects and then call `.live()`. You need *one* selector. So either do:

```
$('#selecto, #matic, #hello').live('click', function() {
   console.log('one of those divs was clicked');
});
```

or define the function beforehand and attach it individually:

```
function log() {
   console.log('one of those divs was clicked');
}

div1.live('click', log);
div2.live('click', log);
div3.live('click', log);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since div1 is already a jQuery object, you can just do

```
div1.live('click', function() {
   console.log('one of those divs was clicked');
});
```

without wrapping is in the jQuery selector $(div1)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need `live`, just use `click`

```
div1.add(div2, div3).click(function(e){ ... });
```

if you don't wanna rewrite the IDs, you could do it this way:

```
var div1 = $('#selecto');
var div2 = $('#matic');
var div3 = $('#hello');

var selector = [];

div1.add(div2).add(div3).each(function(i, val) {
    selector.push("#" + val.id);
});

$(selector.join(", ")).live("click", function(e) {
    console.log(this.id + ' was clicked');
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/roberkules/bvpNX/

Comment: As Felix Kling said, it doesn't work for the live handler. But in general, this would be the way to combine the 3 divs into one group.

Comment: anyways, seems like the wrong usage of live. if you wanna add a click handler to those 3 divs, just bind the click handler, no need for the live functionality.